# List windows on command line

Tags: command-line, xorg

I am interested in finding a window information from command line. The `xprop` command gives good results, however it requires that I either know the window id or select something using the mouse.

What I know is the pid that opened the window, and I know the window title (at least a regex pattern that could match).

So how can I either list all window ids or to find out which window was opened by a specific process?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `wmctrl` to list the windows.

```
wmctrl -l
```

See `man wmctrl` to find what else it can do.

Comment: It comes in an extra package but does exactly what I need. Thank you. :-)

Comment: You are welcome and good luck with wmctrl :-)

Comment: It doesn't list all windows in Ubuntu 22.04 if Wayland is enabled

Comment: @david.perez, Several tools do not work well with Wayland, and I am not surprised that you have problems with `wmctrl`. Anyway, thanks for this heads-up.